# Package 'au.com.bytecode' does not exist (OpenCSV)

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, opencsv

Like the title says. What am I doing wrong? I am using Netbeans, and I created a folder for my 3rd party libraries, right-clicked the Package, navigated:

```
Properties > Libraries > Add JAR/Folder > OpenCSV-2.3.jar
```

and then used

```
import au.com.bytecode.OpenCSV;

class OpenCSV extends au.com.bytecode.OpenCSV {

}
```

But netbeans throws the above error (or removes the import completely) every time I attempt to fix the imports or compile.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a picture of how you've added the JAR to your libraries?

Comment: In what way do you mean? from inside netbeans or from Wind'ohs Exploder?

Comment: [NetBeans](https://p.twimg.com/AzuSLNdCAAAgomk.png) ||| [Wind'ohs](https://p.twimg.com/AzuSOyyCUAAHd4k.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. After exploring the JAR with 7Zip, I discovered that 'opencsv' was a folder, not a class; after adding a '.*' to the end of the import line it started working!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure which Opencsv you are using. I had the same problem because i have added com.opencsv.opencsv maven dependency and expecting was au.com.bytecode.opencsv:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```